# Custom entity with dynamic paths

Tags: 8, routes

I am creating a new entity and would like it to be in the users profile.

The path should be "/user/{user-id}/documents/X":

```php
/*
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/user/{user}/documents/{document}",
 *     "add-form" = "/user/{user}/documents/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/user/{user}/documents/{document}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/user/{user}/documents/{document}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/user/{user}/documents",
 *   },
 */
```

When I enter any page, the following error appears.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route "entity.document.collection". in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 182 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

I have also tried to create the routing.yml file but it still gives the same error.

```yaml
entity.document.collection:
  path: '/user/{user}/documents'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'document'
    _title: 'Document List'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      user:
        type: entity:user
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: As side note, A route like */user/{user}/documents/{document}/edit* or */user/{user}/documents/{document}/delete* is wrong: An entity is unequivocally identified by its ID value, not by the ID for the user who created it and the entity ID. Even nodes have an owner, but the route to delete a node isn't */user/{user}/nodes/{node}/delete*.

Comment: If you want to have a tab for each user to show the documents created by that user, that is fine, but */user/{user}/documents/{document}* should not be the canonical route for an entity, IMO.